# Create PDF file without dictionary data type (angle brackets)

Tags: pdf, dictionary, pdf-generation, brackets

I want to create a PDF file which does not contain angle brackets in it's source.

This apparently implies not using the `dictionary` data type, as this involves `<<` and `>>`.

Is it possible to completely avoid angle brackets and still create a PDF file with formatted content?

Can it be done hiding in a stream, using a character encoding technique or with an alternative dictionary notation?

The solution is needed for an obfuscation technique; the bracket-problem cannot be circumvented.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Is there any underlying problem that you are trying to solve?

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean with "obfuscation technique", what are you trying to obfuscate? PDF files? You can use PDF encryption for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible. Every element in a PDF file is contained in some dictionary: the document catalog (the root dictionary), the page objects, the page content streams, all of them are dictionaries that require the char sequence `<<` `>>`.

Sample catalog dictionary:

```
1 0 obj
<<
/Pages 2 0 R
/Type /Catalog
>>
endobj
```

If you want to use a "instructions sequence only" presentation format, you may try using PostScript instead.

**Edit after comments:**

Using a stream object with some filter encoding will not solve your problem, since you still need to specify the filter type in the stream dictionary.

Example:

```
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
***illegible characters***
endobj
```

Comment: This is indeed an "I want to make an omelet without breaking any eggs" question. Every PDF needs dictionaries. You could try getting all dictionaries in an Object stream, but you won't succeed, because (1) compressed streams could occasionally contain << and >>, but more importantly (2) each stream object starts with a dictionary that contains a length value (number of bytes in the stream) and the filter value (how is the stream compressed).

Comment: Thank you for your answers. The answer is needed for the analysis of an obfuscation technique. As you can choose different stream encodings it is not true, that you have to expect << and >> turning up in the stream. Also remember that there are some encoding possibilities for names with `#` and backslash - which do not seem to work for angle brackets.

Comment: I just wanted to point out, that his argument (1) was not true, while (2) absolutely explains why I can't solve my <<>>-problem. Thank you for your efforts!